# Make a normal query from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

Using VB6 and SQL Server 2000

I want to convert a stored procedure to normal query

Stored procedure:

```
Alter  PROC [dbo].[proc_New] 

    @CCODE VARCHAR(100),
        @EmpCode VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID VARCHAR (5) 
    DECLARE @Des VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @Flag INT
    SELECT @Flag=0
        SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT PERSONID FROM T_PERSON WHERE '
    IF @CCODE<>'All' 
        BEGIN
            IF @Flag=1 
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SQL = @SQL+' AND (CCODE IN ('''+@CCODE+'''))'
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SQL = @SQL+' (CCODE IN ('''+@CCODE+'''))'
                SELECT @Flag=1
            END
        END
    IF @EMPCODE<>'All' 
        BEGIN
            IF @Flag=1 
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SQL = @SQL+' AND (EMPCODE IN ('''+@EMPCODE+'''))'
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @SQL = @SQL+' (EMPCODE IN ('''+@EMPCODE+'''))'
                SELECT @Flag=1
            END
        END

IF @SQL = 'SELECT EmpCode FROM EMPMST WHERE ' SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT EmpCode FROM EMPMST'
INSERT INTO table EXEC(@SQL)
GO
```

Procedure Explanation...

- I am passing 2 parameter values like emp_code or All and company_code or All.
- In the 1st parameter (`Emp_Code`): if the value is "All" means then query return the all the `emp_code` or If the values is "001" then query return the "001" `emp_code` only
- In the 2nd Parameter (`Company_Code`): if the value is "All" means then query return the all the `emp_code` for all the company (ex: IBM, SoftTech, etc) or If the value is "IBM" means then query return all the `emp_code` for that company (IBM)

Above stored procedure is working fine, but I want to convert into normal query.

Can anybody help me

Need query help

Comment: What do you mean by a normal query? Non dynamic?

Comment: Tip: you can change the base query to include `WHERE 1=1`, then you will have a correct syntax, whether you add some `AND <condition>` or not. You can then remove the `@Flag` and the last `IF`.

Comment: What your query actually doing or what do you want to achieve form this query?? So that we can think of alternative queries

Comment: @MGA, I Provide the explanation for the Store Procedure.....

Comment: It's a store**D** procedure - as in **STORED** in SQL Server - it has nothing to do with a "store" ...

Comment: @Gopal, it would probably help to explain why you want to do this. If you have a working stored procedure, why do you need to change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the simpler query, please try with this:

```
SELECT PERSONID FROM T_PERSON WHERE 
    CCODE = (
        CASE WHEN @CCODE = 'ALL'  THEN CCODE
        ELSE @CCODE END
        )
    AND
    EMPCODE = (
        CASE WHEN @EMPCODE = 'ALL'  THEN EMPCODE
        ELSE @EMPCODE
        END
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do this in SQL outside of a stored procedure, your stored procedure has several if/else statements, no structure exists in sql queries to do this, if you want to achieve this you will need to build in sripting logic from the language accessing it with (i.e. c#/php/coldfusion/etc) and then perform the individual queries.

What Language are you calling the stored procedure from, or is this directly from the SQL server?

**Edit:** I have not used VB6 in a while so I don't remember how to write this in VB but you would basically be copying the logic from the stored procedure to build the query and then sending the query directly from VB not letting the stored procedure do it.

e.g.

```
 Dim sql As String
 If CCODE <> 'All'
      sql = 'SELECT PERSONID FROM T_PERSON WHERE AND (CCODE IN (' & CCODE & '));'
      {send the query to sql server}
 End If
```